# Animation add to the Stage

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx, box2d

I created , as you can see below an Animation , but now , I can not figure out how to add to the Stage . Can anyone tell me how ? I searched online and unclear ideas about it . thank you

```
TextureRegion tex1 = new TextureRegion(new Texture("play_anim_1"));
TextureRegion tex2 = new TextureRegion(new Texture("play_anim_2"));
TextureRegion tex3 = new TextureRegion(new Texture("play_anim_3"));
TextureRegion tex4 = new TextureRegion(new Texture("play_anim_4"));

Animation playerAnimation = new Animation(0.1f, tex1, tex2, tex3, tex4);
```

you can do something like

```
stage.addAnimation ( playerAnimation ) ;
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Just like code of m.antkowicz, create class:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;

public class AnimeActor extends Actor{


    Animation animation;
    TextureRegion currentRegion;

    float time = 0f;

    public AnimeActor(Animation animation) {
        this.animation = animation;
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta){
        super.act(delta);
        time += delta;

        currentRegion = animation.getKeyFrame(time, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        batch.draw(currentRegion, getX(), getY());
    }
}
```

for use:

```
AnimeActor anim = new AnimeActor(animation);
stage.addActor(anim);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best idea is to create an actor extending [Actor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html) class that will be wrapping the Animation object. Then in he's **act** mathod you are getting current KeyFrame and in the **draw** method you can render it depending on the actor's position

```
    class MyAnimation extends Actor
    {
        Animation animation;
        TextureRegion currentRegion;

        float time = 0f;

        //... creating animation etc...

        @Override
        public void act(float delta){
            time += delta;

            currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(time, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
            super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
            batch.draw(currentRegion, getX(), getY());
        }
    }
```

Now you can create the actor and just add it to the Stage.

---

This approach is better because:

- You don't need to handle rendering in the render Screen's method
- **The Z-index will be kept always** - in your example the animation will be always over everything since it is rendered after Stage
- You can wrap more code in the single class and even inherit it creating next animation types or joining animation with body etc...

Comment: I can try your idea , you write it in full even with the animation ?

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
public void render () {
    //qui definisco lo stage
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();

    elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(seaAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime,true),100,100);
    batch.end();
}
```